# Dynamically enumerate fields from List<T>

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I'm using the following method to enumerate fields of my classes-

```
EnumerateFields(typeof(Student));

void EnumerateFields(Type type)
{
    PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prp in props)
    {

    }
}
```

It works nicely.

Now I would like to do the same task from a List<>. Pseudo code-

```
EnumerateFields(List<Student>);

void EnumerateFields(List<T>)
{

}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What makes you think you need to do anything more than replace `Student` with `List<Student>` in the `typeof` operator?

Comment: Do you mean the properties of the list? If so, you just made a typo. If not, explain what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want something like this:

```
void EnumerateFields<T>(List<T> input)
{
    PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var r in input)
    {    
        foreach (PropertyInfo prp in props)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prp.Name + " = " + prp.GetValue(r));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure, you're passing in `List<T>`, you can still get the properties of `T` as:

```
private void EnumerateFields(Type type)
{
    Type subType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    PropertyInfo[] props = subType.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prp in props)
    {
        // your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not iterating the items in the list, but you are walking its properties.